# How to load table view with chart data in Angular

Tags: angular, api, angular-material

I have a chart view with backend api with table view. The chart is loading fine with data but table doesn't get any view according to chart. Here's my code and other references.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3 col-md-6 pt-1">
      <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-3" (click)="generateGraph()">View</button>
  </div>
<div class="chk-block-content widget-body">
  <md-tab-group (selectChange)="onTabClick($event)">
    <md-tab label="Graph" style="color: aliceblue">
      <div id='chart-container'></div>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Table">
      <div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr class="bg-dark">
                <th class="numeric">DATE & TIME</th>
                <th class="numeric">Heat Balance(kW)</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let row of dataSource | paginate: { itemsPerPage:20, currentPage: p }; let i = index">
                <td width="50%">{{row.categories}}</td>
                <td width="50%">{{row.dataset}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
            <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1 mb-3" type="button" (click)="exportAsXLSX()">Export to Excel</button>
          </table>

        </div>
      </div>
    </md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
fromdate: string;
  todate: string;
  dataSource: any = [];

  columnsToDisplay = ['']

  optionSelected: any;
  apiEndPointUrl = GlobalItems.API_ENDPOINT;
  isGraphTab: boolean = true;
  p: number;

  constructor(private _excelService: ExcelService, private _service: DashBoardService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(Date.now(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.getReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate);
   // this.getPlantList();
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
  }

  loadChart(fromdate: string, todate: string) {
    var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'zoomline',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      width: '100%',
      height: '400',
      dataFormat: 'json',
    });
    visitChart.setJSONUrl('http://192.168.1.155:9002/api/dashboard/get-heatbalance-data?from=2020/01/12&to=2020/03/12');
    visitChart.render();
  }

  getReportData(fromdate: string, todate: string): any {
   
    this._service.getReportData(fromdate, todate).subscribe((res: any) => {
      // this.data = res;
      this.dataSource = res;
      
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })

  }

  fromDateChanged(newDate: any) {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(newDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.todate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if (this.isGraphTab) {
      this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
    }
    this.getReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate);
  }

  toDateChanged(newDate: string) {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.fromdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(newDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if (this.isGraphTab) {
      this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
    }
    this.getReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate);
  }

  // onPlantChanged(plant) {
  //   this.plant = plant;
  //   this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.fromdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  //   this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.todate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  //   if (this.isGraphTab) {
  //     this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate, this.plant);
  //   }
  //   this.getReportData(this.fromdate, this.todate, this.plant);
  // }

  exportAsXLSX(): void {
    this._excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.dataSource, 'heat-balance');
  }

  onTabClick(event: { index: number; }) {
    this.fromdate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.fromdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.todate = new DatePipe('en-US').transform(this.todate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    if (event.index == 0) {
      this.isGraphTab = true;
      this.loadChart(this.fromdate, this.todate);
    } else {
      this.isGraphTab = false;
    }
  }

  // getPlantList(): any {

  //   this._service.getPlantList().subscribe(res => {
  //     this.plantList = res;
  //   }, error => {
  //     //console.log(error);
  //   })
  // }

  generateGraph(){ 
    this.toDateChanged(this.todate);
  }

}


**service file**
export class DashBoardService {
    private _httpAuthClient: HttpClientService;
      private _controller = 'api/dashboard';
    
      constructor(private http: Http) {
        this._httpAuthClient = new HttpClientService(http);
      }
    
    
     public getReportData(fromdate:string, todate:string):Observable<any> {
        return this._httpAuthClient.get(this._controller + '/' + fromdate + '/' + todate)
      }
}
```

[Back end url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRcq0.png)

I want to know why my table is not loading and any suggestion to fix this issue.

Comment: why did you not just paste the output rather than provide a picture

Comment: also your data stream response is an object not an array

Comment: It's long JSON file so I cropped it to show in brief the format.